# Submit on clicking a radio input on react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, form-submit, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form` and I have to create a radio buttons form that submits when clicking an option. This is the code

```
const Form0 = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const submitFunction = (data) => {
    console.log("submitted:", data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitFunction)}>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="foo" {...register("radio-button")} />
        foo
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="bar" {...register("radio-button")} />
        bar
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="foobar" {...register("radio-button")} />
        foobar
      </label>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I tried adding `onClick={() => handleSubmit(submitFunction)}` on each label but didn't work. Also I tried changing all the input types to `type="submit"`, but when clicking an input always submit the value of the first input.

I created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-radio-p4p9o9

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a ref in your form tag and use this to dispatch the submit event from your radio buttons.

Add the ref:

```
const formRef = React.useRef(null);


<form ref={formRef} ...
```

Add the onClick to your radio buttons:

```
onClick={handleRadioButtonClick}
```

and dispatch the submit event:

```
const handleRadioButtonClick = () => {
    formRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit", { cancelable: true }));
};
```

**EDIT**:

For you sandbox example, you can use `watch` and subscribe to the changes like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch(handleSubmit(submitFunction));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [handleSubmit, watch]);
```

Comment: I've tried to do this but didn't work. It doesn't trigger the onSubmit function

Comment: a sandbox would be helpful then

Comment: I just added a sandbox with the initial code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-radio-forked-mfxgh6?file=/src/App.js